# Explanation - Copying data VBA code using PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I have these two workbooks.

I want to transfer data of some columns in the first workbook to a given sheet in workbook 2.

I am getting an error of runtime (1004).
Method 'Range of object' worksheet failed

I am getting error on this line in the code

```
 SummarySheet.Range(columnaddress & "8:" & columnaddress & lastrow).Copy
```

Here's the complete code .

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim MacroBook As Workbook, SummaryBook As Workbook, BSSBook As Workbook, _
    SummarySheet As Worksheet, TwoGonlyER As Worksheet, threeGswapRoll As Worksheet, _
    threeGswapER As Worksheet, fourGprData As Worksheet, threeGpRData As Worksheet
  Dim onlyER As Range, rolloutER As Range, swapER As Range, prData As Range, _
    gPRdata As Range, FolderPathForSummary As String, lastrow As Integer

  Set MacroBook = ThisWorkbook

  'Summary Book Open
  FolderPathForSummary = MacroBook.Worksheets("Tool").Range("D8")

  FolderPath = MacroBook.Worksheets("Tool").Range("D11")

  If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid folder path to save the file!"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If Not Dir(FolderPathForSummary) <> "" Then
    MsgBox " Summary file doesn't exist in your mentioned address. Please   check again!  "
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set SummaryBook = Workbooks.Open(FolderPathForSummary)
  Set SummarySheet = SummaryBook.Worksheets("Summary Data")

  lastrow = SummarySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  'BSS Tracker Open
  Set BSSBook = Workbooks.Add
  BSSBook.SaveAs (FolderPath & "BSS Tracker " & Format(CStr(Now), "ddmmmyyyyhhmmss") & ".xlsx")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("2G Only ER").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set TwoGonlyER = BSSBook.Worksheets("2G Only ER")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("3G Swap & 4G ROllout ER").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set threeGswapRoll = BSSBook.Worksheets("3G Swap & 4G ROllout ER")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("3G & 4G Swap ER").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set threeGswapER = BSSBook.Worksheets("3G & 4G Swap ER")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("4G PR Data").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set fourGprData = BSSBook.Worksheets("4G PR Data")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("3G PR Data").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)

  Set threeGpRData = BSSBook.Worksheets("3G PR Data")
  Set swapER = threeGswapER.Range("A3:P3")

  For Each entry In swapER

    columnaddress = entry.Value

    SummarySheet.Range(columnaddress & "8:" & columnaddress & lastrow).Copy
    entry.PasteSpecial

  Next entry

  BSSBook.Save
  BSSBook.Close

  SummaryBook.Save
  SummaryBook.Close

  MsgBox "BSS Tracker successfully generated!"

End Sub
```

Comment: If what you entered into the question has been copy/pasted from the VBE, the code won't work.

Comment: I have two workbooks.I want to transfer data of desired columns in workbook 1 to desire sheet of workbook 2.I am getting error in code . [link] (1drv.ms/f/s!AlgPDzGNgeAvgRiR7PqmpUg46TnW )

Comment: Added link in comment to the main question. A bit of light rewriting. If you tell us what exactly the error you're getting is, that might help us find an answer.

Comment: I've formatted your VBA to make it easier to copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, columnaddress should be string variable which should hold the column letter. Like

```
Dim columnaddress As String
columnaddress = "A"
```

There are also other variables like SummarySheet which refers to the source sheet and entry sheet which refers to the destination sheet.

The variable lastrow should be a long variable which refers to the last row with data.

So if lastrow is say 25 and columnaddress is "A" then as per the following line

```
SummarySheet.Range(columnaddress & "8:" & columnaddress & lastrow).Copy
```

Then Range A8:A25 from the SummarySheet is copied and paste on entry sheet.

Comment: I have two workbooks.I want to transfer data of desired columns in workbook 1 to desire sheet of workbook 2.I am getting error in code . [link] (https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlgPDzGNgeAvgRiR7PqmpUg46TnW )

Comment: @AamirHussain That's a different question altogether. I have answered your original question. If you have a new requirement, you should open a new question then. Also take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)

Comment: My question is same sir.I am getting error in code .firstly I post a code line where I am getting error and you gave me an answer but still I am unclear that's why I post links of Excel for complete code

Comment: You just wanted an explanation about the line of code you posted and I explained that. The explanation is enough for you to tweak the code as per your requirement. If you tweaked it and still it is not working, edit your question and add the code you tried. Remember SO is not a code writing service like please code it for me.

Comment: I edit my question.Kindly find out an error in the code.

Comment: @AamirHussain: Is this a puzzle or something to find the error in the code? If you have got an error please include that in the question.

Comment: @Nitish I did revise my question and highlight the error.